# Facebook plugin for Unity: FB.PublishInstall is not showing up in facebook dashboard. Am I doing something wrong in the following code?

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

The following code on IOS returns confirmation in the xcode logs that the debug statements are going off, so every function listed below is working.

Any idea what facebook isn't noticing it?  And yes, I have filled out the code in the settings for unity/facebook menu.

We get responses from the FBPublishResponse function "   Facebook Publish Response: true", so it SEEMS to be working?

```
void Awake()
{
    Debug.Log("***--- FaceBook Enable Called ---***");
    FB.Init (onInitComplete, onHideUnity);
    DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
}

void onInitComplete()
{
    Debug.Log("***--- FaceBook Enable Response ---***");
    fbReady = true;

    Debug.Log("    FB.Init completed: Is user logged in? " + FB.IsLoggedIn);

    FB.PublishInstall (FBPublishResponse);
    Debug.Log("***--- FaceBook Enable Finished ---***");
}

void FBPublishResponse(FBResult response)
{
    Debug.Log ("   Facebook Publish Response: "+response.Text);
}
```

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: Well, it was the most recent then, and the most recent now since I updated it.  We also tried logging in the user with "FB.Login("",onLoginReady);"

Comment: Well, it was the most recent then, and the most recent now since I updated it.  We also tried logging in the user with "FB.Login("",onLoginReady);"  Sadly, none of this is showing up on the facebook systems.  I have checked the App ID several times, and it is correct as well.  Another test was to use the FB.Login("",onLoginReady); option, but loggin in using facebook did not allow the FB.PublishInstall to show up in the facebook logs.  The unity app on xcode is giving no errors and is running each command (checked using debug code)